# Loop returning just one element

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to loop through the images to get the Alt attribute of all, but the code is only returning the first image

```js
const tagged = {
    getImgsAttributes: () => {
        const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('main img')
        for(let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            const allAttributes = imgs[i].getAttribute('alt')
            return allAttributes
        }
    }
}

console.log(tagged.getImgsAttributes())
```

Comment: It's the expected behavior since you are `return`ing inside the loop which means the function will return and terminate at the first iteration.

Comment: Push the `alt` attributes in an array and return that after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store each alt attribute value in an empty array variable with **push()** method.

```js
const tagged = {
  getImgsAttributes: () => {
    var storing = [];
    const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('main img');
    for(let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
      const allAttributes = imgs[i].getAttribute('alt')
      storing.push(allAttributes);
    }
    return storing;
  }
}
console.log(tagged.getImgsAttributes())
```

```html
<main>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcbpv.jpg?s=48&g=1" alt="Image #1">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcbpv.jpg?s=48&g=1" alt="Image #2">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcbpv.jpg?s=48&g=1" alt="Image #3">
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
function img_find() {
    var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('main img');
    var imgAttrs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgAttrs.push(imgs[i].getAttribute('alt'))
    }

    return imgAttrs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to return an array of attributes, you're currently returning just one attribute as your code indicates. The easiest way is using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the list of images

```
const tagged = {
    getImgsAttributes: () => {
        // Use Array#from since querySelectorAll doesn't return a true array
        const images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('main img'));
        return images.map((img) => img.getAttribute('alt'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can map the array and return it:

```
const tagged = {
    getImgsAttributes: () => document.querySelectorAll('main img').map(img => img.getAttribute('alt'))
}

console.log(tagged.getImgsAttributes())
```

Comment: No you can't. `.querySelectorAll()` doesn't return an array